# Using VBA in Outlook to automatically download and store a linked PDF file in a folder (not attachment)

Tags: vba, url, pdf, outlook, save

first post and I'd be extremely grateful if anybody knows the answer here. The closest I've found to what I need is at this link:

[Using VBA in Outlook to Save File on Web/URL/Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350888/using-vba-in-outlook-to-save-file-on-web-url-hyperlink)

Basically, to give context to my problem, I frequently use a system to generate a variety of reports that are then emailed to me. The emails however, do not contain the attachment themselves, but rather are in a stock form with a different link to the PDF file in question, contained within. I want to run a VBA script that will search the email for links fitting a certain form (i.e., the first part before an ID number will always remain the same), and then download the PDF that the link points to in a pre-designated folder on my computer.

I think the second post in the link above is close to what I need, but want I need to be able to parse a variable URL. For example, the URL will take the form similar to:

```
http://example.text/here/Download.aspx?FileID=0123456789
```

with the number at the end changing for each email. The number is contained within the subject header and email itself, but I don't know how to maybe drag this out and store it to a variable for use.

If anybody can please help me, I'll be very very grateful.

Thank you for your time.

Bump? Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub LaunchURL(itm As MailItem)

    Dim bodyString As String
    Dim bodyStringSplitLine
    Dim bodyStringSplitWord
    Dim splitLine
    Dim splitWord
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim FileDestination As String

    bodyString = itm.Body
    FileDestination = "\\sever\folder\report\"
    bodyStringSplitLine = Split(bodyString, vbCrLf)

    For Each splitLine In bodyStringSplitLine
        bodyStringSplitWord = Split(splitLine, " ")

        For Each splitWord In bodyStringSplitWord
            If Left(splitWord, 46) = "http://example.text/here/Download.aspx?FileID=" Then
                            myURL = splitWord

                            Dim WinHttpReq As Object
                            Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                            WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
                            WinHttpReq.Send

                            myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
                            If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
                                Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                                oStream.Open
                                oStream.Type = 1
                                oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
                                oStream.SaveToFile (FileDestination)
                                oStream.Close
                            End If

            End If
        Next

    Next

    Set itm = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub test()
    Dim currItem As MailItem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    LaunchURL currItem
End Sub
```

The only problem i'm getting is to suppress the pop.. but i will need help saving the file... I don't know how to code to capture the file name inside the url.